# How send a Map<String, String> using @PathVariable from Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to receive a `Map<Timestamp, Integer>` as `PathVariable` using Spring MVC. Is this possible?

### This is my controller:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Some Api", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@PostMapping(consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity<RestResult> createApi(@RequestPart (value="image", required = false) MultipartFile banner, SomeRequest request){
    RestResult result = new RestResult();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

### This is my request:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class SomeRequest implements Serializable {

    @NonNull
    private MultiValueMap<Timestamp, Integer> someValue;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As one of the way you could use Spring's `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` and implement its `supportsParameter()` and `resolveArgument()` methods. The last one accepts the method parameter and web request, which you can use to get any required data and compose the object whatever you want.
The argument resolver is invoked before the controller method and makes the required argument transformation.

Update:
You have to register the resolver to make it active. If you use spring-boot, you just need to define it as a bean.

Hope it will help.